# How to find the average of the annual salary using the month's salary in Excel?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

Hi I need to find the the average annual salary using the salary per month data.

I know one can use another column for the salary per year and work it out, but I do not want to, since I am trying to make the application as efficient as possible.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve, but it looks like `=SUM(B2:B4)*12/3` should do it. Or even better, `=AVERAGE(B2:B4)*12`, or `=A7*12` since you already have the average number in its own cell.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you asking this question, since the answer is quite clearly *almost* there in your screenshot?

You just need to put **`sum`** at the start.

Comment: it is giving an error since im conducting an operation with arrays and non-arrays